# Convert Android Cursor to ArrayList of arrays

Tags: android, arraylist, android-cursor

I try to convert my Cursor data to a arraylist<String[]>. But at the end all the data in the arraylist is overwrited with the last row. What do i do wrong?

```
Cursor c = myDbHelper.getLvl1Cata();
String[] data = new String[3];
c.moveToFirst();
while(!c.isAfterLast()) {
    data[0] = Integer.toString(c.getInt(0));
    data[1] = c.getString(1);
    data[2] = Integer.toString(c.getInt(2));
    Log.e("cc", data[1]);
    catalogueData.add(data);
    c.moveToNext();
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this

```
Cursor c = myDbHelper.getLvl1Cata();
String[] data;
if (c != null) {
    while(c.moveToNext()) {
        data = new String[3]; // Note this addition
        data[0] = Integer.toString(c.getInt(0));
        data[1] = c.getString(1);
        data[2] = Integer.toString(c.getInt(2));
        Log.e("cc", data[1]);
        catalogueData.add(data);
    }
    c.close();
}
```

`data` is an array of strings. In the original code, you added the same array to your `catalogueData` structure several times. You changed the value of the array's contents each time, but it was still the same array object. So you ended up with `catalogueData` holding several references to a single array, and that array can only have one value for `data[0]`: the last thing you set it to.

This answer fixes that by using a new and different array for each row in the cursor.

Comment: Hey Waren, I was also doing the same thing, I'm getting error at catalogueData.add(data);, what exactly is that? Please can you guide me through this.

Comment: @Anupam you need to tell me what the error is, otherwise I can't help.

Comment: @WarrenFaith Is there any way to read the cursor and store in the array list in one go. If i don't want to run the loop ?

Comment: @ShivamAgrawal No. The cursor is just a pointer to data and you need to move it by yourself. So looping is the only chance.

Comment: @Anupam catalogueData.add(data); is adding data to arraylist catalogueData. catalogueData variable should be List or ArrayList or something similiar to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if(mycursor!=null){    
            do{
    TextView name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);               
    name.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex
                (Displayname)));
    mycursor.moveToNext();
            }while (mycursor.isLast());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `String[] data = new String[3];` into the while loop.  You're overwriting the array object with each iteration.

Comment: creating a new object in a loop is bad practice in android! See my answer where declaration and initialization is done in two steps.

Comment: @WarrenFaith: Can you clarify what you mean about creating a new object in a loop? Your answer also creates a new object in a loop, although you do separate declaration of the variable from creating the object.

Comment: @LarsH:  His answer would perform the exact same as mine.  It doesn't matter where the declaration is put. If you want to save a collection of Arrays, you have to create a new set of Arrays at each iteration or else the previous one will just overwrite the last set.

Comment: Otherwise if you were just throwing the array away at each iteration then yes, that would be true. You'd want to create the object outside the loop.